# react-native-calendar-strip returns last day's date on dateSelected

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I'm using `react-native-calendar-strip` within my `react-native` application. Normally, `onDateSelected` prop works perfectly, returns the selected date. Whereas, whenever I add `datesWhitelist`prop, it start to return last day's date. I couldn't figure out what is happening.

I'm going to share my `react-native-calendar-strip`component code.

```
<CalendarStrip
                            calendarAnimation={{type: 'sequence', duration: 30}}
                            daySelectionAnimation={{type: 'border', duration: 200, borderWidth: 1, borderHighlightColor: 'white'}}
                            style={{height: 80, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10, marginBottom: 15}}
                            calendarHeaderStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                            calendarColor={'#7743CE'}
                            dateNumberStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                            dateNameStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                            highlightDateNumberStyle={{color: 'yellow'}}
                            highlightDateNameStyle={{color: 'yellow'}}
                            disabledDateNameStyle={{color: 'grey'}}
                            disabledDateNumberStyle={{color: 'grey'}}
                            onDateSelected={(date)=>this.dateSelected(date)}
                            datesWhitelist={datesWhitelist}
                        />
```

And here is my `datesWhiteList` array code.

```
var today = new Date();
var last = new Date();
last.setMonth(last.getMonth()+1);
let datesWhitelist = [{
     start: today,
     end: last
  }];
```